# I have never received an email from StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, email

I have searched all through here and found nothing to fix my problem.

There is apparently an option to receive emails with answers to questions I post--never seen it and I use the latest Chrome browser.

I'm supposed to receive email of my unread inbox every three hours--never received anything. Someone answered a question of mine 10 hours ago and I never got notified.

I use GMail and outlook and my spam folders on both have nothing from SE or SO.

While I've begun participating more on here as I'm working in newer technologies, I think the reason I didn't participate more in the past is I never received any notifications--ever.

The first post I ever made on a StackExchange site simply disappeared into the ether and there is apparently no record of it. I remember a moderator made a change to it which I asked about but never saw a response. Now all trace of the post has vanished.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Double check in your settings on your profile and make sure your email is set to the one you're checking. You can check this by clicking your name on this question, then the "Settings" tab. The page you open up to should have a textbox for the email address to send notifications to.

Comment: I'm not sure that more spam is necessarily something to request :-), but if you want it it's best to post screenshots of your exact settings so that someone in the community might be able to help.

Comment: You only set opt-in two hours ago... you only get *unread* notifications every three hours (as you've set it) - that doesn't include notifying you that a post you made in 2014 was deleted in May... Not quite sure what you're expecting here?

Comment: Why the down votes ?  I have not recieved any emails either, ever (except for two from moderators).  I just checked my email settings and they are correct.  There are probably things I have not responded to and people probably think that I am rude.  I just assumed that my understanding of emails was different to SOs  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I now am receiving my inbox notification email. @Jon Clements, you made the comment that I only set "opt-in two hours ago". I'm not sure what you mean as I never saw an 'opt-in' option. What I did two hours ago was change the inbox dump to 3-hours instead of Daily which it has always been and I have never changed it before.

My assumption, and why I am posting an answer, is that in order to receive email notifications of any kind, you must change something in the email preferences and save them which I had never done since what appeared to be the default settings were fine with me. I guess they weren't the default settings, after all. At least, now I'm receiving emails and I wasn't before.

NFN but I posted the question because after trying repeatedly over months and months to deal with this problem periodically, I was at the end of my ideas and needed help. Since I have received so much help from this site in the past and am now participating more, seeing the responses to my questions and answers was of interest to me. I don't really appreciate being lashed for it.

Comment: I did that @pnuts and so far I've received no mail. However, it appears I've had no further feedback so that does not mean anything. Assuming I eventually see some feedback for something, I will post back here the result.

Comment: I've also (frustratingly) never received an email from StackOverflow in years of using it, being 2021 now. My email settings have always been set to get updates every 3 hours.

Comment: @dan674, as I mentioned in my answer, I have been getting emails, for the last five years, of anything that shows up in my inbox--as I did to see your comment. I truly don't know what made it start working.